# delete array [] elements

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on some data structures - after searching for an element, I am attempting to delete that element - but throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at SearchArray.deleteElements(SearchArray.java:68)
    at SearchArrayDemo.main(SearchArrayDemo.java:25)
```

this is my method

```
void deleteElements(int value)
{
    int j,k;

    for (j=0;j<setArray.length;j++)

        if ( value == setArray[j])

        break;
        if
            (setArray[j] == setArray.length)

            System.out.print("no item found");
        else
        {
            for( k=j;k<setArray.length;k++)

                `setArray[k]=setArray[k+1];`

            k=setArray.length-1;
            setArray[j]=0;

        System.out.println("item deleted");
        }`
```

and main method used to call that functions `deleteElements`

```
sa.deleteElements(5);
```

I did not include all the code for conciseness, this is the line where code breaks

```
setArray[k]=setArray[k+1];
```

please let me know if remaining code is required. thanks all for your help.

Comment: Debug your code for easier and better life.

Comment: We cannot get in to your machine and debug code for you. And the exception is self explanatory. The index you are trying to access is not present.

Comment: before this line setArray[k]=setArray[k+1]; YOu need to put a check whether k=Array.length-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your loop end condition is

```
k<setArray.length
```

, but then you use

```
setArray[k+1]
```

Change the condition to

```
k < setArray.length - 1
```

Comment: OK I can see the obvious mistake now, I always confuse `.length` method with the index - it does not throw an exception now.

Answer (score 1):

```
for( k=j;k<setArray.length;k++)

setArray[k]=setArray[k+1]; \\ K+1 (invalid index when k = setArray.length-1
```

In your code, this will fail for the last element. Hence you get the exception

In an Array last index will be `Array.length-1`. In your case for the last element the code fails because `k=Array.length-1` (last index) and `k+1 = Array.length` (which does not exist). Hence it throws out of bounds exception.

Your first for loop has some dead-code:

```
if(setArray[j] == setArray.length)
  System.out.print("no item found");
```

This condition will never be reached in your loop `for (j=0;j<setArray.length;j++)`

Comment: thanks for your detailed analysis - `if(setArray[j] == setArray.length)
  System.out.print("no item found");` this line checks if no item is found -

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this snippet:

```
for( k=j;k<setArray.length;k++)
           setArray[k]=setArray[k+1];
```

When `k == setArray.length - 1`, `setArray[k+1]` goes beyond setArray boundaries

Comment: there was a mistake in my answer. it should be: "when k == setArray.length - 1"

Comment: @sitko - this line `setArray[k]=setArray[k+1];` will move higher order elements down one step -

Answer (score 1):

if u want to delete the element in array 4

```
 class arrayserch{
 public int value(){
   int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5,6;
     int i=0;
     for(int a:arr){
     if(a==4){
     return i;
   }
  else
  i++;

  }
return=-1;
 }
 }





     class example{
      public static void main(string arags[]){
     arrsearch as=new arrrsearch();
      int i=as.value();
       if(i!=-1){
       arr.length--;
       for(int j=i;j<arr.length;j++)
       {
         arr[j]=arr[i++];

           }
         }
         }


this may solve ur problem
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont't know your code
but line

```
setArray[k]=setArray[k+1];
```

it's out boundaries array

Comment: the mistake is pointed out above - it was `k < setArray.length - 1`